# Approximations of reals by prime ratios

Tags: number-theory

Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem shows how it is possible to find a rational approximation as close as required to any real number.
Has it been proved whether there always exists a ratio of two primes as close as required to any real number?

Comment: Many thanks - just what I was looking for. Apologies for duplicating.